# How do you mark unique occurrences in a pattern given that value are unique when occurring simultaneously and not when they come separately?

Tags: sql, r, excel, sas, worksheet-function

Suppose my data looks like this

```
   student article.bought
1        A            pen
2        B         pencil
3        V           book
4        A            pen
5        A      inkbottle
6        B            pen
7        B         pencil
8        B         pencil
9        V           book
10       Z         marker
11       A      inkbottle
12       V           book
13       V            pen
14       V           book
```

I need unique occurrences of articles probably in a different column like this

```
   student article.bought Occurences
1        A            pen          1
2        B         pencil          1
3        V           book          1
4        A            pen          1   # as A is taking a pen again
5        A      inkbottle          2   # 'A' changed from pen to ink bottle
6        B            pen          2
7        B         pencil          3   # though B took pencil before, this is different as he took a pen in between
8        B         pencil          3
9        V           book          1
10       Z         marker          1
11       A      inkbottle          2
12       V           book          1
13       V            pen          2
14       V           book          3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.The articles should be uniquely flagged.If a Student takes an article it should be flagged as 1,the next article as 2 and so on.If the article is immediately repeated the number should remain the same and if the article is repeated after taking some articles in between,then that article should be considered as a different article

Comment: so you want to increase a numeric value whenever within one student there is a transition from one article to another? Is the  original sort order of any significance? What should this numeric value do when a transition occurs to a product the student used before (but not immediately before ... e.g. pen-book-pen)?

Comment: Yes,want to increase a numeric value whenever within one student there is a transition from one article to another.

Comment: Shouldn't 11. ink bottle be 2? It hasn't changed since the last occurrence of A.

Comment: Yes, the sort order is significant.The numeric value should also increase when the transition occurs to a product the student used before. For a student,pen can be 1 and for another it can be 3..

Comment: Yaa..its a mistake. Its '2' for A-inkbottle. Changed it above.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in a particular language? R, SAS, Excel, SQL?

Comment: answer in R or SQL will be more helpful. If not, then Excel or SAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, we can find changes in a student's selection by finding the difference, `diff`, of each subsequent value. When we take the cumulative sum, `cumsum`, of that logical index we get a running count of occurrences.

In the second line we coerce the factor variable `article.bought` to numeric and run the function from the first line using `ave` to group the function `f` by student.

```
f <- function(x) cumsum(c(F, diff(x) != 0)) + 1
df$Occurences <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(article.bought), student, FUN=f))
df
#    student article.bought Occurences
# 1        A            pen          1
# 2        B         pencil          1
# 3        V           book          1
# 4        A            pen          1
# 5        A      inkbottle          2
# 6        B            pen          2
# 7        B         pencil          3
# 8        B         pencil          3
# 9        V           book          1
# 10       Z         marker          1
# 11       A      inkbottle          2
# 12       V           book          1
# 13       V            pen          2
# 14       V           book          3
```

Comment: Yes!! Its working.. Thank u so much.. Very Helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. create additional column [Original Sort Order] and enumerate from 1
   to ...
2. sort table by student / orig sort order
3. enter `=IF(A2=A1,IF(B2=B1,D1,D1+1),1)` in D2 and copy down
4. convert column D to values (copy, paste as ... Values)
5. restore original sort order

If this is more than a one-off, use the same tactic to create a VBA script

[image]

Comment: Nice one.Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

A shot with SAS:

```
data try00;
length student article $20;
infile datalines dlm=' ';
input student $ article $;
datalines;
A pen
B pencil 
V book 
A pen 
A inkbottle 
B pen 
B pencil 
B pencil 
V book 
Z marker 
A inkbottle
V book 
V pen 
V book
;

data try01;
set try00;
pos=_n_;
run;

proc sort data=try01 out=try02; by student pos article; run;

proc sort data=try02 out=stud(keep=student) nodupkey; by student; run;

data shell;
length occurrence 8.;
set try02;
if _n_>0 then delete;
run;

%macro loopstudent();

data _null_; set stud end=eof; if eof then call symput("nstu",_n_); run;


%do i=1 %to &nstu;
data _null_; set stud; if _n_=&i then call symput("stud&i",student); run;

data thisstu;
set try02;
where student="&&stud&i";
dummyart=lag(article);
retain occurrence 0;
if dummyart ne article then occurrence=occurrence+1;
else occurrence=occurrence;
drop dummyart;
run;

proc append base=shell data=thisstu; run;

%end;

proc sort data=shell out=final; by pos; run;

%mend loopstudent; %loopstudent();
```

dataset "final" has the result.